# Google cloud Wordpress limiting access by IP-address

Tags: .htaccess, google-compute-engine, http-status-code-403

I'm using Wordpress on Google Cloud compute engine and I am trying to keep my website from being live while I build it.

I use a lot of custom code outside of the Wordpress building environment, so I cannot simply use the Wordpress option to not publish a page.

I have tried using an *.htaccess* file, but, as was predicted by some, it does not seem to work. (However, I did see some occasional 403s, on my mobile phone for example. That confuses me.)

Content of .htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 'My IP without quotes'
```

The purpose is to limit access to all but a few IP-addresses. If there is another way to keep the site from being live while allowing for testing, that would be just as good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just password protect it? You can use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Then create a file named `.htpasswd` and then correct the path for `AuthUserFile`.

Inside your `.htpasswd` it would look like this:

```
admin:dg8T958shL
```

So username and password - Just keep in mind that you **WILL** need to correctly encrypt your password for it to work. You can do that using this [tool](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/).

So if somebody tried to access the website, they would be presented with the following:

[image: Security]

Only those who know the logins would be able to proceed to view the website and run tests on it.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. It is what I do for my site. You could also add code so that the website does not cache. That is especially helpful while testing.